# What are the standard externs provided by the command line Google Closure, and how do I get them through the Java interface?

Tags: java, javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm currently using this code:

```
com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Level.OFF);
com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler compiler = new com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler();
CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
CompilationLevel.ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);
WarningLevel.VERBOSE.setOptionsForWarningLevel(options);

List<JSSourceFile> externs = new ArrayList<JSSourceFile>();
externs.add(JSSourceFile.fromFile(extern_src));

List<JSSourceFile> primary = new ArrayList<JSSourceFile>();
primary.add(JSSourceFile.fromFile(tmp));
compiler.compile(externs, primary, options);
```

However, I get lots of errors like this:

```
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Array is undefined
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable TypeError is undefined
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Object is undefined 
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable arguments is undefined
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Number is undefined
Error message: JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Math is undefined
```

Obviously, these are not correct: things like `Object` and `arguments` etc a core part of the language. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see Michael Bolin blog regarding using the Java API?

http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html

Comment: I don't see anything different other than using Strings instead of Files that he's doing—I don't think that should cause the issue. Could you elaborate if this is not the case>

Comment: You need the default externs.  See getDefaultExterns() in
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java